# Add thickness to medical image

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing

I can't change the outer surface because it's a medical file. How to throw a thickness into it? To be able to 3d print it on the 3d printer.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read, because we have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges or Moiré patterns, hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver malfunction, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: It is mandibular jaw

Comment: What do you mean by adding thickness? what file format is that, can you open it / import to Blender? If you can't change the surface, how do you plan to add this thickness / 3D print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add outline to your rendered objects by post-process effect called [Freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/index.html). For a scene with a single object, the setup is very easy:

1. Enable freestyle with your render engine - both Eevee and Cycles can do it (although they might produce different results).

[image: Enable freestyle in engine tab]

2. Configure your line set. You can find it in the *View Layer* tab all the way at the bottom. Deselect everything except for `Silhouette` - this will be your outline, we want nothing else.

[image: Line set configuration]

3. **(Optional)** If you want to print your render, set the world color to white to save some ink :)

[image]